# Headers forget chapter name

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

I'm trying to insert headings in my report using `fancyhdr`. I want the current chapter's name on the right corner of each page (one sided document). the problem is that when, inside a chapter, I add the second `\section`, the heading doesn't work and only the chapter number appears, not the name.

I know that the problem is inside the `\titleformat` line I wrote, but I don't know how to fix it. I need that `\titleformat` instruction in order to let a line appear under each chapter name, and to avoid the word "chapter nr." to appear at the beginning of each chapter.

Could anyone help me?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\chapter}
   {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. \ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[L]{\chaptermark}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{test_chapter1}
        \section{test_section1}
            \lipsum[1-15]
        \section{test_section2}
            \lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\chaptermark` is executed by `\chapter`. Normally it sets the left and/or right mark for page header/footer using `\markboth` or `\markright`. And this marks (`\leftmark` and/or `\rightmark`) can then be used inside `\fancyhead` or `\fancyfoot`.

So you have to use

```
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\titleformat{\chapter}
   {\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{\arabic{chapter}}{1em}{}[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. \ #1}{}}
\fancyhead{}% <- added
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}% <- changed

\begin{document}
\chapter{test chapter1}
\section{test section1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\section{test section2}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you load `titlesec` load it with option `[pagestyles]`: it's so much simpler with package `titleps`! Here's a code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage, 12pt, italian, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{font=small}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{}{\thechapter~\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}

\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{test-chapter1}
        \section{test-section1}
            \lipsum[1-15]
        \section{test-section2}
            \lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

[image]